# CS:GO - How to join competitive servers?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I have, so far, only played cs:go by clicking **Browse community servers** and join a few of my favorite servers (mostly low ping and friendly people). Now I am getting a little better on the game I though about playing competitive to see what rank I can get, but I have a doubt.

Does the only way to join competitive servers is by clicking **Find a game** and selecting **competitive**? **Community quick-play** and **Browse community servers** are just casual (non ranked)?

*I ask this because I would like to see a list of competitive servers to I can choose the one I want, but I believe **Find a game** option just choose the server for you.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is the only way. You can also create a group of friends before you do so and enter the game with your friends on your team and go on a pub stomp. But matchmaking is the only way to enter a competitive match.

Answer (score 2):

I don't feel the answer marked as the answer is correct. The

> Find a game and selecting competitive?

uses the built in matchmaking and does indeed put in you the competitive server. These servers are generally referred to as "official" servers.

**But is it the only way? *No***, it's not. There are external services such as [ESEA](http://play.esea.net/), [ESL](http://www.esl.eu/) and [CEVO](http://cevo.com/) and the like that also allow you to run a Competitive game on their servers.

I'm not going to get in to the differences of the servers but they are different and they are running the competitive game mode.

I recall these services giving you a bit more insight in to the servers prior to queuing for a game.